# Using same default UIImage object for cell reuse/initialisation

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiimage

I have a doubt regarding using a default UIImage stored in `Assests.xcassets` during cell configuration in the `tableView` delegate method `_cellForRowAtIndexPath_`. Consider the following code snippet:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:newItemCellResueId , for: indexPath) as? MyCustomCell
    cell?.imageView?.image = defaultImage
    //After this we do all other stuff that needs to be done with the cell
    return cell
}
```

where defaultImage is a stored property of my class which is initialised like this:-

```
var defaultImage = UIImage(named: "Default")
```

Now my question is this. Since an *image*  is a subview of a cell's *imageView* , when I set cell's imageView.image to be equal to the instance of my stored property I assume it will be added as a subview to that cell's imageView.If it is so, how is that single default UIImage instance being added as a subview to multiple cells? If not, does it generate different instances of this UIImage and add them to the cells? If yes , why don't we worry about the memory footprint(caching etc) of all those instances of defaultImage (like we do for Asynchronously fetched images for the TableViewControllers)

Comment: The image isn't a subview. `UIImage` doesn't inherit from `UIView`. The image is rendered in the image view. It is essentially a bitmap. That bitmap can be rendered by any number of `UIImageView`s simultaneously.

Answer (score 2):

> Since an image is a subview of a cell's imageView

No, it's not. `image` is just property of `UIImageView` of type `UIImage?` for image, displayed in the image view ([docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimageview/1621069-image)).

Now, if you have default image for cell, you don't have to worry about "the memory footprint" and you can set it inside `cellForRowAt`

```
cell?.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "Default")
```

Answer (score 2):

`UIImage` is not a subclass of `UIView` and it is not added as a subview of your `UIImageView`. `UIImageView` is a `UIView` that can render a `UIImage`.

Since `UIImage` is an immutable object, multiple `UIImageViews` can safely refer to the same `UIImage`.

The `UIImage(named:)` initialiser uses an internal in-memory cache, so whether you use a single property with your default image, or use the `UIImage(named:)` initialiser repeatedly has no impact on the memory footprint of your app.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

1. Add new Imageset from Assets.xcassets. And Name it "test"
2. It will print tableview with 5 time images.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.delegate=self
        tableView.dataSource=self
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell:UITableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:"cell") as UITableViewCell!
        cell.imageView?.image=UIImage(named:"test")
        return cell
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 5
    }

}
```